# Back button working differently from Navigator.pop

Tags: flutter, dart, navigator

I have a 4-page application, whenever I push the back button it goes back to the main page. I added a button with an onPressed like this

```
onPressed: () => {
  Navigator.of(context).pop()
},
```

and it goes back from the fourth page to the third.
I even wrapped the widget inside a WillPopScope but the behavior is the same.

I access every page with a Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute).

Are there some cases where a back button will behave differently from a Navigator.pop?

Comment: Did you put any logic inside the onWillPop () {}?

Comment: Probably its best to check this documentation https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics because your syntax is a little different when going to a screen and back.

Comment: can you explain what behaviour do you want ?

Comment: @ManishDayma that when I press the back button, it shows the previous page (eg from 4th to 3rd) instead of going from the x-th to the main one.